# update total not working on cart page for table rate shipping methods magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I have enabled table rate shipping method in magento. Now in cart page I am getting a section called Estimate Shipping and tax. 
Now in this section when I am selecting a country and clicking on estimate then I get the shipping rate according to the tablerates.csv file that I have uploaded through magento admin panel in

System->Configuration->Sales->Shipping Method->Table Rates

section.Now when I select the rate and click on update total then total is not getting updated. This problem I have on my live site.
Then I installed magento on local and does the same process, here the total gets updated when I click on update total section.
Then I checked controller action for update total button. The action of the form that contains the button is

action="http://{{site-url}}/checkout/cart/estimateUpdatePost/"

Now when I compared the estimateUpdatePost action on local and live then found that content is same

Content of estimateUpdatePost action on localhost

```
public function estimateUpdatePostAction()
{
    $code = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_method');
    if (!empty($code)) {
        $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($code)/*->collectTotals()*/->save();
    }
    $this->_goBack();
}
```

Content of estimateUpdatePost action on live

```
public function estimateUpdatePostAction()
{
    $code = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_method');
    if (!empty($code)) {
        $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($code)/*->collectTotals()*/->save();
    }
    $this->_goBack();
}
```

Now both the function is same.I could not understand why the total is not getting updated on live. Could anyone help me proceed in right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was one of the modules. Enabling and disabling the modules got me know the module due to which update total was not working.